# Google Compute Engine traffic limit

Tags: web-hosting, bandwidth, google-compute-engine

The instance that I created seems to have an external network upload limit of about 4MBps. Is there a way the increase that limit?

The instance has more than enough RAM an CPU (n1-standard-8: 8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory), but the hosted sites froze and begging to give timeout when the instance reaches 3MBps or 4MBps of outgoing network activity.

Tried searching in the GCloud site, but I can't seem to find the answer.
Maybe I am searching for the wrong terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

An n1-standard-8 instance can egress [16Gbps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps) (and can also typically ingress in the gbps also), so GCE itself is not the limit you are hitting.  Some other possibilities are:

- You are reading/writing from disk at one end, and the disk is only capable of 4mbps.
- One end of your connection has a fully busy CPU, and there is simply delay doing to processing to sending and receive data.
- The other end of your connection has a maximum throughput of 4mbps.
- There is congestion - ie if you 4k connections over 16Gbps, each will only get 4Mbps.
- Your connection is high latency and short-lived. High latency connections can take a long time to get to full throughput, and often are totally unable to saturate a connection.
- You have packet loss. Even 1% packet loss can very significantly hurt TCP throughput.